# Spring MVC RedirectView to AngularJS URL with parameters

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to redirect my users to an AngularJS style URL:

`http://somedomain.com/#/oauth/authorize`

And I have some parameters I'm adding to the URL via my model.  So far, so standard.  Right up until Spring MVC takes a dark and sinister turn inside of [`RedirectView`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/86b7118da8732f7602b4d94762c27f09f633e44c/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.java#L400) at line 400.  If you click that link you'll see the comment:

`// Append anchor fragment, if any, to end of URL.`

No!  This is not good for AngularJS!  That would make my normally beautiful redirect:

`http://somedomain.com/#/oauth/authorize?query=params`

look like:

`http://somedomain.com/?query=params#/oauth/authorize`

This is bad juju!

So I have two questions:

1. What purpose does this arrangement of anchor and query params serve.
2. How do I circumvent this devilish machinery?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I need to take a shower after doing this, but this is a possible solution.

Place this in your main script (i.e. `app.js`) immediately before creating the module in which you configure your `$routeProvider`.

```
var urlLoaded = window.location.href;
var qIndex = urlLoaded.indexOf('?');
var hashIndex = urlLoaded.indexOf('#');

if (qIndex !== -1 && hashIndex !== -1 && qIndex < hashIndex) {

    var correctedPath = urlLoaded.substring(hashIndex);
    var correctedParams = urlLoaded.substring(qIndex, hashIndex);
    var base = urlLoaded.substring(0, qIndex);
    var correctedUrl = base + correctedPath + correctedParams;

    window.location.href = correctedUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are in the early stages, I would look into using HTML5 pushState. This way you can use anchors like they were meant to be used, and you url's will look cleaner. There are browser limitations to this, and other considerations, but getting it in correctly might save you time down the line from running into this again.
- You can extend this class, override the method, and fix it to be smarter than it currently is. Register it with spring (it might take a couple of overrides, look at ViewControllerRegistry), and if you're feeling nice, submit a Pull Request and see if they want it.
- Beat that URL back into submission in angular as @hartz1989 has suggested
- Instead of doing a redirect, you could respond back with a query parameter that has the redirected url, and add a handler in angular that understands this and does the "redirect". I don't really like this idea, but it is another idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The pushState in Angular seems to not play nice with AWS's CloudFront - I can't do any URL rewriting, unfortunately.  #2 is an option that I'm looking into.  #3 is what I've adopted as a short term fix.  #4 isn't an option for my particular use case because the redirect is deep in Spring Security OAuth2's machinery.  But I could always submit a pull request there too.